# Passthrough Nintendo Switch data from one USB port on a PC to another USB port on the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: usb, controller

I'm attempting to setup a Parsec cloud streaming console for myself.

Lets also say I plug my controller into the PC using one USB port, but then hookup the console to the PC using a usb cable (male-male) and another port (USB 3.1). Could I redirect the port that the controller is connected to, to the port the console is connected to, allowing the two to communicate? Like a KVM switch I suppose but implemented by Windows.

It seems like it would be possible, you could just get Windows to gather information from the controller, then based on that info act like it's the controller to the console, then vice-versa with the controller and act like the console. Then from there just output whatevers input into the controller port out the console port and vice versa.

But thats just my immediate guess, so is this actually possible to do?

I've read that USB 3.1 is symmetrical - can act as both device and host. I've also found this repo that can mitm/emulate usb devices but requires a microcontroller in the middle: https://github.com/usb-tools/Facedancer.git

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using sys-hidplus homebrew for the switch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).